# How to use Summernote with a form tag?

Tags: html, summernote

I want to use Summernote with a `<form>` tag. I tried these two options:

```
<div id="summernote" name="summernote"></div>
```

and

```
<input id="summernote" name="summernote">
```

inside a `<form>` tag, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: "it didn't work for me" doesn't describe the problem you are having. Do you mean the Summernote editor is not being displayed, or the content of the editor is not being submitted to your server, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

in html you do:

```
<div class="summernote">summernote 1</div>
```

in jQuery you do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.summernote').summernote();
});
```

and you got your editor.

Make sure you have included `summernote` properly as well.